# connectionstring 500 error Azure IoT

Tags: azure, web, iot, azure-iot-hub

Have deployed a test device that sends to Azure IOT then alerts into Dynamics 365.

I am trying to view data from a web app using https://github.com/Azure-Samples/web-apps-node-iot-hub-data-visualization

Once completed I open web page and get a 500 error with below in log:

Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
ArgumentError: Connection string doesn't have EntityPath, or missing argument path at Function.EventHubClient.fromConnectionString (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure-event-hubs\lib\client.js:92:11)

I used the connectionstring below from the IoTHub -> Endpoint -> Events -> Event Hub Compatible Endpoint :

set Azure.IoT.IoTHub.ConnectionString=sb://iothub-ns-****************r-451891-d07caf9987.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=zNy3a*******************CZyjCoTpXdem0=

I have also tried to run locally and added EntityPath to connection string with no success.

I did notice in Azure that it has a warning for my IoTHub:
Some IoT Hub features are disabled due to the location of your resource. The following are the impacted features: Events

Could this be an issue?

Comment: Can you provide your azure iot hub resource location so we can find out if it is resource limitation issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested again and added the "primary key" connection string from:
Shared Access Policies -> iothubowner and it worked.